# What is the maximum percentage of people who have studied neither $A$ nor $B$?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

In school $X$, $40\%$ of students have studied a language at some point during their school education, and 20% have studied history at some point in their school education. What is the maximum percentage of people who have studied neither?

---

I was thinking:

All = $100\%$

$P(L) =$ language ; $P(H)$ = history

$P(L) + P(H) - P(L \cap H) + P(\text{neither}) = 100\% $

$0.4 + 0.2 - P(L \cap H) + P(\text{neither}) = 1$

$P(\text{neither}) = 0.4 + P(L \cap H)$

So $P(\text{neither})$  is max when  $P(L \cap H)$ is max. That happens when all the ones studying $H$ also study $L$. So that would be 20%

$P(\text{neither}) = 0.4 + 0.2 = 0.6$

What do you think?

Comment: What happens if all history students also took a language?  What happens if *none* of the history students also took a language?  What is $P(\text{neither})$ equal to in the two cases? ¶ One way to think about this is to use inclusion-exclusion: $P(\text{neither}) = 1-P(\text{either}) = 1-[P(\text{language})+P(\text{history})-P(\text{both})]$.  You know what $P(\text{language})$ and $P(\text{history})$ are; now consider the possible range of $P(\text{both})$.

Comment: I don't follow how you arrived at the conclusion of "the minimum value of $P(L\cap H)$ leads to the maximum value of $P(neither)$..."   $0.4+x$ gets bigger the bigger that $x$ is.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yeah you are right I got confused. I thought it was a minus.

Comment: @JMoravitz what about now? 0.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your working before this step is all good:

> $P(\text{neither}) = 0.4 + P(L \cap H)$
>
> The minimum value of $P(L \cap H)$ leads to the maximum value of $P(\text{neither})$.

Correction:

The ***maximum*** value of $P(L \cap H)$ leads to the maximum value of $P(\text{neither}).$

---

Alternatively, visualise a Venn diagram:

[image]

We want to maximise the number of outcomes in the shaded region. As such, encase event $H$ entirely within event $L:$

[image]